# pam pam_sm_authenticate try to get get user and password of non esixting users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sshd, pam

I am trying to get the user and password of the enter users via ssh , but I can only see the passwords of the users that are registered and the non registers user's (Ubuntu users) I get the string "INC" . I am trying to replace the Ubuntu authentication and test if the users is legit via my own db and if so redirect the default user and password . my code :

```
int pam_sm_authenticate(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    const char *user = NULL;
    const char * password=NULL;
    int pgu_ret, snp_ret, a_ret,retVal=0;
    int i =0,pam_err=0;
    FILE * fp =fopen("/var/log/test_pam_debug.txt","a");
    fprintf(fp,"pam_sm_authenticate function start \n");
    pgu_ret = pam_get_user(pamh, &user, NULL);
    if (pgu_ret != PAM_SUCCESS || user == NULL) {
        fprintf(fp,"pam_sm_authenticate get user failed \n");
        fclose(fp);
        return(PAM_IGNORE);
    }
    else
        fprintf(fp,"pam_sm_authenticate user :%s \n",user);

    /* get this user's authentication token */
    retVal = pam_get_authtok(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, &password , NULL);
    if (retVal != PAM_SUCCESS) {
        if (retVal != PAM_CONV_AGAIN)
        {
            fprintf(fp,"auth could not identify password for [%s]\n", user);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(fp,"conversation function is not ready yet \n");
        }
        fclose(fp);
        fprintf(fp,"retVal : %d \n ",retVal);
        return(retVal);
    }
    else if(password)
        fprintf(fp,"user=%s, password=[%s]\n", user,password);
    /*TODO : here i will check the user && pasword via db in if so continue else return  PAM_USER_UNKNOWN*/
    if ((pam_err = pam_set_item(pamh, PAM_RUSER, "default_user")) != PAM_SUCCESS)
    {      printf("\n pam_set_item( pamh, PAM_RUSER, rad) error msg : %s  and return code : %d \n ", pam_strerror(pamh, pam_err),pam_err);
        fclose(fp);
        return(PAM_USER_UNKNOWN);
    }
    if ((pam_err = pam_set_item(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, "default_userPwd")) != PAM_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("\n pam_set_item( pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, rad123) error msg : %s  and return code : %d \n ", pam_strerror(pamh, pam_err),pam_err);
        fclose(fp);
        return(PAM_CRED_INSUFFICIENT);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return(PAM_SUCCESS);
}
```

I compiled it as `.so` and addeed this to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` auth sufficient `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_test.so`

my prints in `/var/log/test_pam_debug.txt`

`user=wewe, password=[ ]` for unknown or sometimes

2.. `user=jhjh, password=[ IN]` and for known users it prints it user password (not what the user has typed and I can't seem to change it)

Answer (score 1):

found the issue at :https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/can%27t-get-auth-token-for-non-local-users-with-pam-module-945164/
basically the problem is that er can't get password from unknown user's , Linux PAM will replace the password with `\b\n\r\177INCORRECT` if it cannot obtain information regarding the user from the system databases (Name Service Switch, see man nsswitch.conf).
possible workaround check with getpawn that the user does exists.
example:

```c
/* The actual pam functions are merely wrappers around succeed_if */
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    const char * password=NULL;
    struct passwd *pwd;
    const char *user;
    int pam_err=0;
    /* identify user */
    pam_err = pam_get_user(pamh, &user, NULL);
    if (pam_err != PAM_SUCCESS)
    {
        return (pam_err);
    }
    if ((pwd = getpwnam(user)) == NULL)
    {
        return (PAM_USER_UNKNOWN);
    }
    /* note : if user is not defined password return will be "^H$^M^?INCORRECT^@" */
    pam_err  = pam_get_authtok(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, &password , NULL);
    if (pam_err!=PAM_SUCCESS)
    {
        return (pam_err);
    }

    /* here add personal auhtentication */
    pam_err = isAuthenticate((char *)user,(char *)password);
    if (pam_err != PAM_OK)
    {
        return (PAM_AUTH_ERR);
    }

    return (PAM_SUCCESS);
}
```